# Undefined variable: partner laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have controller

```
 public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'image' => 'sometimes|image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png',
        ]);
        $partner->update([
            'name' => $request['name'],
        ]);
        if (request()->file('image')) {
            $partner->update([
                'image' => request()->file('image')->store('images', 'public'),
            ]);
        }
        return redirect()->route('partner.index', $partner);
    }
```

and blade

```
<form action="{{ route('partner.update', $partners->id) }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
@method('PATCH')
@csrf
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="username" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Отображаемое имя</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10"><input class="form-control" type="text" value="{{ $partners->name }}" id="name" name="name"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
         <label for="image" class="col-form-label">Изображение</label>
         <input id="image" type="file" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('image') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="image" value="{{ old('image', $partners->image) }}">
         @if($partners->image)<img src="{{ Storage::url($partners->image) }}" alt="" style="width: 150px">@endif
             @if ($errors->has('image'))
                 <span class="invalid-feedback"><strong>{{ $errors->first('image') }}</strong></span>
             @endif
      </div>
      <img src="{{ Storage::url($partners->image) }}" alt="{{ $partners->name }}" style="width:150px;">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect">Обновить</button> <a class="btn btn-primary waves-effect" href="{{ route('partner.index') }}">Назад</a>
</form>
```

I get

> Undefined variable: partner

Comment: Just read the error again and see where you have `$partner` variable

Comment: try    return redirect()->route('partner.index', compact('partner'));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are passing **partner id** not partner **collection object**

so use like that

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'image' => 'sometimes|image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png',
        ]);

        $partner = Modelname::findOrFail($id);   //add this line (add your modelname)
        $partner->update([
            'name' => $request['name'],
        ]);
        if (request()->file('image')) {
            $partner->update([
                'image' => request()->file('image')->store('images', 'public'),
            ]);
        }
        return redirect()->route('partner.index', $partner);
    }
```

Comment: Depending on how the OP's route is defined I'd say that making use of Route Model Binding per my answer would be better as to not make any superfluous requests to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Without much to go on, I'm guessing that you're trying to make use of Route Model Binding, and therefor have forgotten to change your parameter name in your controller.

```
 public function update(Request $request, $id)
```

Should be

```
 public function update(Request $request, \App\YourPartnerModel $partner)
```